# Why d(z^2-x^2) and d(y^2-z^2) join to form dz^2 orbital?

Tags: hybridization

The possible combinations are xy,yz,zx ,d(x^2-y^2) , d(y^2-z^2),d(z^2-x^2) 7 total for d , but i heard that from Scrodinger equation one concludes that only 5 are possible but i dont see how intuitevly or via some reasoning one gets this may someone provide a brief reason for this?

Comment: I personally never really understood that argument either. I think the straightforward answer is to actually solve the Schrodinger equation; you don't get 6 or 7 solutions from it, you can only get 5, because $m_l$ is constrained to be $\in \{-2, -1, 0, 1, 2\}$. One way of putting it would be that even if you made a 6th or 7th wavefunction, it would not be *linearly independent*, i.e. it would not be a genuinely new wavefunction but rather a combination of the existing five.

Comment: That said, I'm not hugely keen on writing an answer unless you explain what you were told more precisely. It's not clear what "the possible combinations" means - who came up with these combinations, and how were they generated?

Comment: Sir by possible combinations i mean x,y,z possible orbitals which might form 3C2 ways of choosing and 3C2 ways of x^2.. ones that i was telling . I just did a bit combinatorics in this nothing  else.

Comment: May you show how they are linearly independent or some stuff Sir it might give me clue and some text references which is easier to understand ?